# What is the meaning of "I am good" to a particular question (vide my elaborate question for the context)

Tags: meaning-in-context

In a recent chat conversation, I asked someone quite high up in my global organization but not belonging to my regional org setup - "Shall I send an email copying my supervisor", and he replied in the chat window with a "I am good". What does it mean?

I wanted an opportunity to introduce my supervisor to him through email, but what should I make of his response?

Is he asking me to send the email (OR) is he asking me not to send the email?

Comment: Only the "high up" is going to know exactly what he meant by it. However, it seems a little too late to get clarification from him.

Comment: I am good = I am all set (the way I am, not with whatever you offered). Send no email.

Comment: In so far as the OP is seeking merely practical advice on how to deal with matter, the comment by @YosefBaskin probably constitutes an adequate answer. For the purposes of this site, it would, however, be interesting to take this question as an opportunity to explore whether 'I am good' used in this way is different from 'I am fine', which is also sometimes used for the purpose of declining an offer, and what reason would anybody have to choose 'I am good'.

Comment: However, "I am good" could also mean "I'm happy with that suggestion" (so send the email copy). It might be a rarer interpretation but it's still a possibility. So clarity should have been sought at the time.

Comment: That person should have said, to be clear, "You're good". I'm good would mean: I don't need it.

Comment: An important distinction is that *I am well* means one thing and *I am good* does not mostly refer to health, and is not an incorrect substitute

Comment: Thank you @ KillingTime YosefBaskin jsw29 & Lambie for your responses / insightful /light hearted comments. This is my first question, and I am already enjoying this forum.

Yeah I just responded "Thank you" to his "I am good" and kept quiet. If and when he asks me tomorrow that have I sent that email out, then I would definitively know the answer to this question - in which case I will share it here. 

Thank you friends!

PS: some arcane rule says I can only use one @user at a time, so sorry if I couldn't tag you all, in the right way.

Comment: Possibly related to "When I'm good and ready" or "I'm good if you are"? Although I don't have a conclusive answer.

Answer (score 2):

This generally means that they don't need you to send the email, they're already satisfied. It's definition 1h in [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/good)

> **informal** : having everything desired or required : content and not wanting or needing to do anything further
> *"Do you want anything else to drink?" "No thanks, I'm good."*

Comment: Yes, I would interpret this as a polite "No, thank you".

Comment: Thank you @Barmar for the response. Sorry I do not have enough points to upvote. As you and all other commenters have mentioned, nothing happened, so I think he was "good" with my NOT sending any email.

Comment: @psmears - thank you for your response.